# What is the "less than followed by dash" (<-) operator in Golang?

Tags: go

What is the `<-` operator in go language? Have seen this in many code snippets related to Go but what is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You've already got answers, but here goes.

Think of a channel as a message queue.

If the channel is on the right of the left arrow (<-) operator, it means to dequeue an entry.  Saving the entry in a variable is optional

```
e <- q
```

If the channel is on the left of the left arrow operator, it means to enqueue an entry.

```
q <- e
```

Further note about "dequeue" (receive) without storing in a variable:  it can be used on a non-buffered queue to implement something like a "wait/notify" operation in Java:  One coroutine is blocked waiting to dequeue/receive a signal, then another coroutine enqueues/sends that signal, the content of which is unimportant.  (alternately, the sender could be blocked until the receiver pulls out the message)

Answer (score 18):

`<-` is used in more than one place in the language specification:

> [Channel types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types):
>
> The `<-` operator specifies the channel direction, send or receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bi-directional. A channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by conversion or assignment.
>
> [Receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator):
>
> For an operand `ch` of channel type, the value of the receive operation `<-ch` is the value received from the channel `ch`. The type of the value is the element type of the channel. The expression blocks until a value is available. Receiving from a nil channel blocks forever. Receiving from a closed channel always succeeds, immediately returning the element type's zero value.
>
> [Send statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements):
>
> A send statement sends a value on a channel. The channel expression must be of channel type and the type of the value must be assignable to the channel's element type.
>
> ```
> SendStmt = Channel "<-" Expression .
> Channel  = Expression .
> ```

The receive operator is also a fundamental part of the [select statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)

Comment: The arrow gives a hint of the direction of flow of data. Personally, I prefer the Occam-Pi syntax of ? for input instead of <-ch (? hints at querying the channel) and ! for output instead of ch<- (! hints at commanding the channel)

Comment: I wonder why the arrow always points to the left. Why didn't they use <- and ->?

Comment: What if the left side is empty? eg: case <-ticker.C:

Answer (score 3):

> [Receive operator](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator)
>
> For an operand `ch` of channel type, the value of the receive operation
>   `<-ch` is the value received from the channel `ch`.

It receives a value from a channel. See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator

Comment: Stack Overflow requires more than just a link. I fixed it for you.