# What is the difference between = and <- in golang

Tags: go

```
func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "processing job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        results <- j * 2
    }
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
    jobs := make(chan int, 100)
    results := make(chan int, 100)
    for w := 1; w <= 4; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }
    for j := 1; j <= 20; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)
    for a := 1; a <= 20; a++ {
        <-results
    }

    t = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

I am confused of the "<-" and I can not find any related documents about "<-". So what is the difference between <- and =?? why I can not use = here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the "less than followed by dash" operator in go language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926697/what-is-the-less-than-followed-by-dash-operator-in-go-language)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is related to channels in Go. You are thinking it's related to assignment as in other languages. In your code, a value "j" is being sent to the channel "jobs".

https://gobyexample.com/channels

Answer (score 26):

The [= operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) deals with variable assignment as in most languages. It expresses the idea of wanting to update the value that an identifier references. The [`<-` operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) represents the idea of passing a value from a channel to a reference. If you think of the channel as a queue using an assignment operator `=` would assign the reference to the queue to the target variable. The receive operator `<-` is equivalent to dequeuing from the queue and assigning the value of the item to the target variable.

You cannot use the operators interchangeably because of a type mismatch. Please note the links to the Go specification which speak at greater length to the operators.

Answer (score 13):

- "=" is assignment,just like other language.
- <- is a operator only work with **channel**,it means **put** or **get** a message from a channel.
- **channel** is an important concept in go,especially in concurrent programming.you can try this [Channel TourPage](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2)  to see its using scene.

Answer (score 0):

This example is meant to illustrate the usage of channels and of the `<-` notation, so if it's still confusing, providing annotation/explanation should help:

```
func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    // each worker will be a goroutine
    // it has an integer id, 
    // the notation `jobs <-chan int` means `jobs` is a channel
    //   of ints, and that `worker` can only read from the channel
    // the notation `results chan<- int` means results is also
    // a channel of ints, and that `worker` can only write to 
    //   the channel

    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "processing job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        results <- j * 2 // This notation means `j * 2` is 
                         // written to the channel `results`
    }
    // so the job the worker is doing is multiplication by 2
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)

    // jobs and results channels of capacity 100
    jobs := make(chan int, 100)
    results := make(chan int, 100)

    // We start running 4 worker goroutines
    for w := 1; w <= 4; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }
    
    // We load up the jobs queue with 20 jobs
    for j := 1; j <= 20; j++ {
        jobs <- j // This syntax means `j` is written 
                  // to the channel `jobs`
    }
    close(jobs) // Signals that we won't be adding any more jobs

    // We wait until we've pulled 20 expected 
    // results from the results queue
    for a := 1; a <= 20; a++ {
        <-results // This syntax means we pull an element out of 
                  // the results queue and discard it (since we 
                  // aren't assigning to any variable)
    }

    // Count how much time all that work took
    t = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```